# Einstein summation with gamma matrices

Tags: tensor-products

Given that 
$$\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu}+\gamma_{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}=2g_{\mu\nu}I$$
Where I is the 4x4 identity matrix, and
$$\gamma^{\mu\dagger}=\gamma^0\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^0$$
Use $|\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi|^2$ to show that from the Dirac equation $\gamma_{\mu}p^{\mu}\psi=m\psi$, the relation $E^2=p^2+m^2$ can be obtained.

The $\gamma$ matrices are 4x4 matrices and $\psi$ is a 'bi-spinor' which is an object I don't really understand, but is apparently a column matrix with four complex components. At a guess the way to find the magnitude is to multiply $\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi$ by the Hermitian conjugate, which gives 
$$(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi)(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi)^{\dagger}=\gamma^{\mu}(p_{\mu}\psi)\gamma^{\mu\dagger}(p_{\mu}^{\dagger}\psi^{\dagger})$$
$$=\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}\psi(\gamma^0\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^0)p_{\mu}^{\dagger}\psi^{\dagger}$$
Can't see what I can do from there, so I also tried rearranging the Dirac equation to:
$$(\gamma_{\mu}p^{\mu}-m)\psi=0$$
The multiplying that by $(\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m)$, which it seems like it might also possibly give me the magnitude:
$$=(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}p_{\mu}p^{\mu}-m\gamma^{\mu}p_{\mu}+m\gamma_{mu}p^{\mu}-m^2)\psi$$
Although I'm not entirely sure that's correctly multiplied out, because it doesn't give me what I'm after - in either of the approaches I've tried, where have I gone wrong?